# Can IIS7 run on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, iis-7

I'm stuck temporarily with a Win XP SP3 workstation, and would like to install IIS7 -- but don't know if it will work properly on WinXP.  Some of the verbiage on MSDN suggests that it will, but it isn't clear.

Anyone know for sure if this is a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [IIS.net](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2010/07/12/how-to-install-iis7-on-windows-xp.aspx):

> Ever since IIS7 shipped in Vista I’ve been asked the question: how can
>   I install it on Windows XP?  Until now, that hasn’t been possible. 
>   With the recent release of WebMatrix, you can now install [IIS Developer Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) - which is based on the latest IIS7x codebase - on
>   any supported Windows operating system including Windows 7, Windows
>   Vista SP1+, Windows XP SP3+, Windows Server 2003 SP2+, Windows Server
>   2008, Windows Server 2008 R2.

I've used this on XP and it's more than adequate for what you're asking.